# Run multiple new terminals from terminal

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I tried to find solution but I don't know how to do it.
I want to start terminal on raspberry pi x times, to run python scripts in paralel.

I tried `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` but nothing did what I wanted or wrote command not found.

This cmd:

```
#!/bin/bashint
for word in $(cat inputs.txt); do python3 enttest.py $word; done
```

This command gets every line from `inputs.txt` file and passes it as parameter to a python script which runs for x hours (one line, one parameter).
I need it to start x terminal based on how many lines there is in the `inputs.txt` file. I want this automatic because the inputs will be generated/dynamic. The script is very simple and I manually started 12 terminals which worked fine on slow raspberry.
Input file can look like this:

```
input1
input2
```

No crazy stuff with the inputs like space or special character. I will have more parameters in future in the input files but those can be separated by delimiter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that without starting new terminals. If you do this:

```sh
#!/bin/bashint
for word in $(cat inputs.txt)
    do python3 enttest.py "$word" &
done
```

bash will execute the scripts in parrallel (it will create a new process for each call), due to the single ampersand (&) after the command.

So the program should execute rather quickly, and then the `python3 enttest.py` tasks will work in the background.

You can read more on that here : https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: `bash /home/pi/Desktop/runMultiple.sh` I run it inside this shell script which I changed to executable but I am getting this error `syntax error near unexpected token ';'` ...so the semicolon is the issue....

Comment: Ah yes I edited my answer, you actually need to use a line break instead of `;` here. Tell me if that worked for you!

Comment: `./runMultiple.sh: line 3: $'\r\r': command not found` this does not work for me too.

Comment: That's weird it works for me with a dummy program. And I don't know where the `\r` comes from. Try putting quotes around `$word` maybe ?

Comment: I recreated the file and I am not getting this error anymore...it was originally created on W10 and then moved to Pi and the second one is from Pi. Anyways...I do not see any prints in terminal, I understand it's running in the background, but shouldn't I see some prints from the python script?

Comment: Well it depends if your script produces output or not. If it does, you should indeed see the output printed onto your terminal. To check if the program is running, you can try `ps -aux |grep python`.

Comment: And by the way, when you run programs in parallel this way, they're not attached to the terminal anymore, so the only way to stop them if they're going on for too long is to kill them (so you do `ps -aux |grep yourprogram`, find the pid (it should be the second column) and then `kill -9 $pid`)

Comment: thanks...it's running in the background. But I don't see the python prints anywhere so I don't even see the error log if something goes bad. Any idea how to do this or maybe start the new window terminal and not this background run?

Comment: @Jakub The stdout is still supposed to be attached to your terminal, so you should see everything it outputs. Does your program outputs stuff in the terminal when you run it on its own ?

Comment: Yes. When run one by one I get plenty of messages which I expect and some other information which I need.

Comment: Well I have no idea why this is. Maybe you could try redirecting the std out and stderr to a log file ? `python3 enttest.py "$word" > "$word".log 2>&1 &` so each instance's stdout and stderr will be redirected to a new file called "$word".log

Comment: I can't test it now, but everytime I put double quotes around `$word` it stopped being variable and got changed to string as it should be i guess.